# Window.location.replace isnt working using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, href, window.location

I am trying to change the url of the page every time it goes through the for loop but it is not working. I am using Google Chrome.

```
var url = "blahblah/";
for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< 10; j++){
       url = url + i + j;
       window.location.replace(url.toString());
       var url = "blahblah/";
   }
}
```

Nothing happens. I have also tried window.location.href = url;

Comment: No wonder, your code seems not to be JavaScript. Omit the type declarations, and everything should go fine...

Comment: Teemu means that you just need to change `int` into `var` to make it *javascript*. May I ask what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Once you get rid of the syntax errors, the code will update the page URL **once**.

Comment: umm also, it's only going to iterate once.. when you change `window.location` it's going to load the new url, whole page reload

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Actually your solution is better than mine : ). I've used to use only one `var` per function, sometimes I just forget people usually declare variables when they are first needed...

Comment: @user3339242 Hmm... Actually you should still get an error, `window.location` is an object which hasn't `replace` method...

Comment: @Teemu Im not sure but it changes the url. The only problem I have now is that when it changes the url it doesn't change it to the next url according to the for loop.

Comment: @user3339242 I'd really love to help you, but even after reading the third time your question I don't realize what's all that for...

Comment: I'm amazed if it works =O, but after reading Crayon Violent's comment, everything should be obvious? Whenever you load a new page, the old page and its loops are gone - forever...

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i` - this is not valid JavaScript. Change to `for (var i`